# change contactinfo relay

Tags: relays

I have a tor relay, and I've changed the contact info in it (misspelled my email adress). I'm running the relay on a raspberry pi 2 using raspbian, installed through the raspian repos.

I have restarted the service and it is listed as restarted on atlas, but the old contact info is the same, but the info on my torrc is up to date.

My relay (if it is of interest) https://atlas.torproject.org/#details/CBFF7A3CB3224A8D8E4C542DDCF0DB47E85B397A

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the latest descriptor, published (currently `2016-08-31 12:12:16`) the contact address currently matches whats on atlas from which I assume it's already been updated.

The update *should* be within an hour, when you restart Tor it will republish your relays descriptor to the DirAuths and then the updated descriptor will be redistributed with the next consensus, which happens hourly. However note that Atlas can lag behind a little, it pulls its data from [`onionoo`](https://onionoo.torproject.org/) which can be delayed a little longer.

A quick way to see the latest descriptor is just to fetch it directly from a Directory server by making a simple `GET` request for [`/tor/server/fp/<your relay's fingerprint>`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n3426) to their advertised DirPort, for example I received this descriptor:

```
router TheNorth 94.255.146.58 9001 0 9030
platform Tor 0.2.5.12 on Linux
protocols Link 1 2 Circuit 1
published 2016-08-31 12:12:16
fingerprint CBFF 7A3C B322 4A8D 8E4C 542D DCF0 DB47 E85B 397A
uptime 2
bandwidth 2097152 3145728 458752
extra-info-digest 0BFED77DF742FA6FAC7E4A4225BCFA87E748B408
onion-key
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAL/j4X5ZPjlWNVOURkyDfihSUJdtf7aF6JtrtthKYGZGf+8ooflXGgJ/
V47HFD/Yd8sMw0aVUPRD4c2BKOHEjREBn/tG2czZDfgTJCnJXZF8b3rw2AhYLnah
J3vCIPGBsOaVZB3epppXxALkzTTxHQTAUdZL7x0hLOAy7ktjvwO7AgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
signing-key
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBALXsXjFe4gpwmfInQRLIVNGOOQShd4VPQwpOF1oywLKuLVWwE1PZC0pp
Tm3LqXlu8fUvEsviGDU2rdX5h1DmEBt8V9goKAC3LgzfDgCs6KJdQxMG7BZBXcpu
hW5GrHfs54/DsAXP2hj9xYcoBgjqINeyzrrOyIBLmS8P0YVDf9vZAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
hidden-service-dir
contact Gustav Andersson <Gustavlidingo at gmail (dot) com >>>
ntor-onion-key PTbY8uOHg/a0ZOQns0/X++Vp8pKguRNnI47/4b3lLDM=
reject *:*
router-signature
-----BEGIN SIGNATURE-----
ratka1yOsSGiI1w55ATF1xZ13OIv4gultSfNt8Xm1uyCr/0fgi55HFLuLLrHm8w+
XJnyeXKISFTNxSqzMUFMJ4aMK2bRElGZsjkAErUObVBCqIP6aTxb3A/K7iyELYI4
kNIjDVyrj2XJU9ZPNOFTntn0ly3CCVQxkk/SvkOU/6A=
-----END SIGNATURE-----
```

*Also see [SuperSluether's answers](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/12477/12737) comment about upgrading Tor, 0.2.5.12 is a few stable releases old now.*

Answer (score 0):

It should update sometime in the next few hours.

If I may suggest, Tor 0.2.5 is very old. You should use the official Tor Repository so you can get the latest version: https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en

To clear up confusion, the Raspberry Pi 2 and newer work fine with this. It's just the older Pis that have problems. Someone should update that page.